# Object doesn't support this property or method in jsp page

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In my jsp page, I have in the `<head>` tag, the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/static/js/common/common.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Function for Suppressing the JS Error
    function silentErrorHandler() {return true;}
    window.onerror=silentErrorHandler;

</script>
```

If there is some JavaScript executing on the jsp page after this, then I guess `silentErrorHandler()` will have no effect. i.e. the error will still show on page. Is this correct? Because the error is showing and am not sure why.
The second part of the question is this:
The error is

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; AskTbFXTV5/5.9.1.14019)
Timestamp: Fri, 7 Jan 2011 21:26:23 UTC
```

> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
> Line: 613
> Char: 1
> Code: 0
> URI: http://localhost:9080/Claris/static/js/common/common.js

And finally, line 613 states

```
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP);
```

There is error on IE8. Runs fine on Mozilla and IE7.
Any suggestions will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error points to a line inside the script file that is loaded before you set the onerror suppression.

If you put it before you include common.js, it should work.

That said, you should really try to find the error and fix it... or wrap it in a try/catch if the exception isn't **really** an issue.

e.g. in your case (using IE) you will get an error because [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in IE does not have a `document.captureEvents` property/method.

Comment: Thanks. But how come it works in IE7? if document.captureEvents is not a prperty/method in IE?

Comment: are you running in IE8 Standards mode? if so, it might be running in a "more" strict mode... vs. IE7 which may silently swallow it for "compatibility reasons". It also might be that this line falls into a bit of code that isn't executed in IE7 (we would need to see the full code to determine that) if you can drop it in http://pastebin.com and link to it we can debug it there.

Comment: So in newer IE8, we can do :document.onmouseup = someFunction; without having to do :document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP); Correct?

Comment: @Kaushik that's correct. If you plan on doing a bunch of JavaScript work you may want to look into a library that helps abstract away the differences between browsers, like jQuery, dojo , mooTools etc. As they make everything "just work". ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I understand dojo has quite a few features. Can you please point me to a link that will make it easier to get started? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> how come it works in IE7?

`captureEvents()` is an unpleasant, unreliable event interface from the Netscape 4 era that was always doubtful and should not be used for anything. Newer versions of both IE and Firefox drop support for it. It sounds like your scripts need some fairly serious updating.

Adding an error sink is also a pretty bad idea. Sweeping your errors under the carpet makes your error-finding job more difficult, and doesn't affect regular users (since they will have browsers' default settings of not opening a report for JS errors).

> So in newer IE8, we can do `document.onmouseup = someFunction;` without having to do `document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP);` Correct?

Yes, but that's using ‘bubbling’ rather than ‘capturing’. In this case the events will still be fired on the descendent elements, and will ‘bubble’ up through each of the ancestors until it hits the document.

The idea of ‘capture’ is that the ancestor element (document) can prevent the descendent elements getting any notification of the event at all. Event capturing isn't often needed in practice and is a pain because it's done differently on different browsers.

IE uses the `setCapture()` method. Other modern browsers use the W3C DOM Events model, passing `true` as the third argument to `addEventListener()` (this doesn't work with the DOM 0 event model of assigning a function to `onclick` et al). `captureEvents()` was how it was done in ancient Netscape. Other older or niche browsers have no means of event capturing at all.

In general: best avoid event capturing. Check the script really requires it. Possibly not: if this is a script intended to run on Netscape 4 (retch), it may have used `captureEvents()` even if it didn't need capturing, because there were some broken parts of the Netscape event model that didn't work right with bubbling.