# dojo cross browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, dojo, cross-browser, compatibility

I recently posted a question on stackoverflow about the less popular js function `document.captureEvents()`. For most browsers, it is not necessary to use this capture. The question and answers are here:
[javascript :Object doesn't support this property or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630492/javascript-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method)

However, it was suggested to be absolutely safe, a dojo solution should be used to abstract away browser differences.
I found some dojo code samples on the web related to generic usage i.e. using dojo syntax to declare form inputs etc.
But is there an example to use dojo for this particular problem of `document.captureEvents()`.
In short, how to do `document.captureEvents` in dojo. Is dojo suited for this particular problem case?

Comment: There are several JS frameworks that provide the kind of abstraction you're looking for. Dojo is one of them; [jQuery](http://jquery.com) is worth a peek too

Comment: Strange...my search does not reveal how dojo can be applied to replace document.captureEvents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dojo makes handling events very easy. If you wanted to capture mouse up event on the page as your other question seems to do, you would use:

```
dojo.connect( dojo.body(), 'mouseup', function( event ) { console.log( event ); } );
```

Replacing the function body with whatever functionality you need.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your real question involves how to properly capture events in modern browsers, in which case you might like to start with a page such as this:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/events.html

As Pekka hinted at, pretty much any successful JS lib today (jQuery, Dojo. Prototype, MooTools, YUI, etc.) provides abstractions involving listening for DOM events.  In Dojo the analogue is `dojo.connect`.

- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/connect.html (reference guide)
- http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/connect#dojo.connect (API doc)